# Elastic Filebeat does not index into custom indices with mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am trying to configure Filebeats to index events into a custom-named index with a custom mapping for some of the fields.
The problem is that Filebeat does not send events to my index but tries to send them to the default '**filebeats-xxx**' index instead, and is failing with parsing/mapping exception since the events do not conform to the default filebeat event format (that's why I want to use my own mapping).

See details below.

UPDATE 09/10/2021:
after finding a similar issue reported/discussed here: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/11866 I tried to follow the workaround and added the following parameter to the filebeats.yml to disable ILM in ES:

```
setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

This did not help much - filebeat logs were saying that ILM is already set.
So I've added one more parameter:

```
setup.ilm.overwrite: true
```

and after this - the errors stopped, but when I try to push events through - filebeat seems to be hung after the following logs:

```
    2021-09-09T21:42:58.057-0400    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:143  Connecting to backoff(elasticsearch(https://testbeats1.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243))
    2021-09-09T21:42:58.391-0400    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.14.1
    2021-09-09T21:42:58.495-0400    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:151  Connection to backoff(elasticsearch(https://testbeats1.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243)) established
```

I don't think it is a connectivity issue as the log says that a connection is established .... Any idea how to debug it further?

END of UPDATE

Here are the details:

I'm getting events from a GCP PubSup topic using the gcp-pubsub input type. The events are being received successfully (confirmed via using the Console output )  - wrapped into a lot of GCP/filebeat specific meta info. If I send an event like this to PubSub topic:

```
{
    "referer": "https://blog.zoom.us/",
    "activity_ip": "1.1.1.1",
    "activity_date": "2021-09-08",
    "logstash_id": "m_id_1",
    "event_timestamp_millis": "1631126426000",
    "cid": "1234567",
    "ref_param": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS aarch64 13421.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/86.0.4240.199 Safari/537.36"
  }
```

the actual event received by Filebeats (and printed on the console when using the Console output) looks something like this:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-09-09T15:49:52.948Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "7.14.1",
    "_id": "59279bf715-2924539382735950"
  },
  "message": {
    "referer": "https://blog.zoom.us/",
    "activity_ip": "1.1.1.1",
    "activity_date": "2021-09-08",
    "logstash_id": "m_id_1",
    "event_timestamp_millis": "1631126426000",
    "cid": "1234567",
    "ref_param": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS aarch64 13421.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/86.0.4240.199 Safari/537.36"
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "gcp-pubsub"
  },
  "ecs": {
    "version": "1.10.0"
  },
  "host": {
    "ip": [
      "xxxx", ...
    ],
    "mac": [
      "...", ...
    ],
    "hostname": "xxx.home",
    "architecture": "x86_64",
    "os": {
      "platform": "darwin",
      "version": "10.16",
      "family": "darwin",
      "name": "Mac OS X",
      "kernel": "20.2.0",
      "build": "20C69",
      "type": "macos"
    },
    "name": "xxx",
    "id": "AB905FFC-D83C-5512-B33A-AA1286026867"
  },
  "agent": {
    "name": "xxx,
    "type": "filebeat",
    "version": "7.14.1",
    "hostname": "xxx",...
  },
  "event": {
    "id": "59279bf715-2924539382735950",
    "created": "2021-09-09T15:49:52.936Z"
  }
}
```

The actual event that I am sending is stored in the "**message**" element. By default, it comes as a String, but since I am sending JSON and want it to be treated as a JSON doc with fields/values - I have added the following Filebeats Processor to the filebeats.yml:

```
- decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
```

(see the full filebeat.yml config below)

I also want to use my own types for the event fields - for example use '**ip**' type for ip fields, date types for all date-specific fields , etc. This is why I wanted to use my own mapping for these events., and send them into an index with a name of my choosing - for example just for testing, it was '**marina-**xxx':

The full mapping/template I came up with is specified below .
At first, I tried putting it as a '**marina_es_template.json**' file into the filebeat root dir and let Filebeat upload this mapping - so I tried the following config:

```
setup.template.name: "marina"
setup.template.pattern: "marina-*"
setup.template.json.enabled: true
setup.template.json.path: "marina_es_template.json"
setup.template.json.name: "marina"
setup.template.enabled: true
```

This did not work - filebeat was not uploading the template correctly - I could not find it in my ES (using ***GET _template/marina**** command). So I have loaded it into my ES manually, using PUT command - and it worked fine, I can see the template listed in ES, and the content of the template is correct.

So, the final issue I was trying to solve was to make Filebeat actually send the events into a 'marina-test1' index and have the mapping applied correctly to this index - by matching on the index name pattern

I've added this config for ES output:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  index: "marina-test2"
```

and used this template settings:

```
setup.template.name: "marina"
setup.template.pattern: "marina-*"
setup.template.json.enabled: false
```

And still Fielbeat keeps trying to send the incoming events into a '**filebeat-**xxx' index and fails with the following error:

```
{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [message] of type [text] in document with id '59279bf715-2924626396675533'. ....}
```

which is correct, since in the '**filebeat**' mapping the field '**message**' is supposed to be a text, not an object ...

So, the question is: how do I force Filebeat to send events into my 'marina-xxx' index, and not 'filebeat-xxx' one???

Thank you!

Here is my **filebeat.yml**: (removed comments/unused fields for clarity

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:
- type: gcp-pubsub
  enabled: true
  project_id: my-project
  topic: logs-for-es-marina
  subscription.name: logs-for-es-marina-sub
  credentials_file: /mydir/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
  fields_under_root: true

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================
setup.template.name: "marina"
setup.template.pattern: "marina-*"
setup.template.enabled: false

## also tried this - but did not help:
#setup.template.json.enabled: true
#setup.template.json.path: "marina_es_template.json"
#setup.template.json.name: "marina"

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  index: "marina-test2"

  hosts: ["https://<my_es>:9243"]
  username: "<my-user>"
  password: "<my-pwd>"
  
# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
```

full ES template mapping:

```
PUT _template/marina 
{
   "index_patterns" :
     ["marina-*"],
     "settings":{
       "index": {
         "number_of_shards":3,
         "number_of_replicas":1
      }
      },
      "mappings":{
          "_source":{
            "enabled":true
         },
              "properties" : {
         "message": {
            "properties":{
            "logstash_id":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "event_timestamp_millis":{
               "type":"date"
            },
            "activity_date":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
            },
            "cid":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "activity_ip":{
               "type":"ip"
            },
            "ref_param":{
               "type":"text"
            },
            "referer":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "user_agent":{
               "type":"text"
            }
         }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own answer - after I got this working:

The key is to disable ILM (Index Lifecycle Management) in the filebeat.yml, and to start from a clean slate if you had any lingering templates/indices/aliases from your previous experiments.

The following two actions got me to a working Filebeat, indexing data from GCP PubSub into custom indices in ES:

1. stop Filebeat
2. clean out all existing indices/templates (ILM policies - if you had any defined for this index pattern) - by "all" I mean all relevant ones, for the indices and patterns you are trying to use in ES; the following commands were usefull:

   DELETE <my-index-name-pattern>*

   DELETE _template/<template-name>
3. disable ILM in **filebeat.yml** - in the "Elasticsearch template settings" group:

   `setup.ilm.enabled: false`
4. start Filebeat

Answer (score 0):

As the [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/ilm.html) states :

> If index lifecycle management is enabled (which is typically the default), setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern are ignored.

Setting `setup.ilm.enabled: false` is the way to go !

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, my yaml would look something like this:

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:
- type: gcp-pubsub
  enabled: true
  project_id: my-project
  topic: logs-for-es-marina
  subscription.name: logs-for-es-marina-sub
  credentials_file: /mydir/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
  fields_under_root: true

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.name: "marina"
setup.template.pattern: "marina*"
setup.template.enabled: false
setup.template.overwrite: true

## also tried this - but did not help:
#setup.template.json.enabled: true
#setup.template.json.path: "marina_es_template.json"
#setup.template.json.name: "marina"

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  index: "marina-test2-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

  hosts: ["https://<my_es>:9243"]
  username: "<my-user>"
  password: "<my-pwd>"
  
# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```